# spring boot no serializa a json

Tags: json, spring-boot

Estoy desarrolando una aplicación web con spring boot. Cuando realizo una consulta mediante un `jparepositoy` del tipo findAll pretendo obtener la lista de usuarios y su rol correspondiente. En la respuesta obtenida se convierten a `json` correctamente todas las propiedades de mi entidad **Usuarios** a excepción de la propiedad que encapsula el objeto rol.

Estas son las entidades Usuarios y Roles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class Usuarios { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id_usuario;

    @Column(name ="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name ="surname")
    String surname;

    @Column(name ="login")
    String login;

    @Column(name ="password")
    String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name ="rol")
    @JsonIgnore
    //@JsonBackReference
    private Roles rol;


    public Usuarios() {

    }
}
```

---

```
package es.pdv.daw.proyect.beans;
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Roles {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idRol;

    @Column(name ="rol_name")
    private String rolName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="rol", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //@JsonManagedReference
    private List<Usuarios> usuarios= new ArrayList<>();

    public Roles() {

    }
}
```

---

```
package es.pdv.daw.proyect.controller;

@RestController
public class ConsultasRestController {

    /**
     * Propiedad que encapsula el objeto de acceso a DAO.
     */
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping(value="dameUsuarios",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Usuarios> loadArticulos(List<Usuarios> usuarios){


    return loginService.findAllUsers(); 
    }   

}
```

---

Este es el `json` obtenido. Como se puede apreciar no se ha incluido el rol.

```
[{"name":"Jose Antonio","surname":"Bernabe Duran","login":"bubu","password":"bubu","idUsuario":1},{"name":"Alexis","surname":"Bernabe Pineda","login":"alex","password":"2010","idUsuario":2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente encontré el error. Se me había olvidado implementar la interfaz serializable a las entidades y tras modificar esto retire las etiquetas `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonManagedReference` y `@JsonBackReference` y todo funciona correctamente.

#### Usuarios

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class Usuarios implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id_usuario;

    @Column(name ="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name ="surname")
    String surname;

    @Column(name ="login")
    String login;

    @Column(name ="password")
    String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name ="rol")
    private Roles rol;


    public Usuarios() {

    }
```

#### Roles

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Roles implements Serializable  {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idRol;

    @Column(name ="rol_name")
    private String rolName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="rol", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Usuarios> usuarios= new ArrayList<>();

    public Roles() {

    }
```

#### JSON

```json
[  
   {  
      "name":"Jose Antonio",
      "surname":"Bernabe Duran",
      "login":"bubu",
      "password":"bubu",
      "rol":{  
         "idRol":1,
         "rolName":"Administrador"
      },
      "idUsuario":1
   },
   {  
      "name":"Alexis",
      "surname":"Bernabe Pineda",
      "login":"alex",
      "password":"2010",
      "rol":{  
         "idRol":2,
         "rolName":"Usuario"
      },
      "idUsuario":2
   },
   {  
      "name":"Maria Luisa",
      "surname":"Pineda Uber",
      "login":"ml",
      "password":"1979",
      "rol":{  
         "idRol":1,
         "rolName":"Administrador"
      },
      "idUsuario":3
   },
   {  
      "name":"Rafael",
      "surname":"Martin Lopez",
      "login":"Rafa",
      "password":"rafa",
      "rol":{  
         "idRol":2,
         "rolName":"Usuario"
      },
      "idUsuario":4
   }
]
```

Comment: deberías aceptar la respuesta haciendo click en el tilde a la izquierda. Más info: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Es porque la propiedad ROL la tienes anotada con `@JsonIgnore` lo que hace que no se serialice ese campo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando la referencia de Rol en Usuario a:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name ="rol")
//@JsonIgnore quitamos ignore   
private Roles rol;
```

Y Agregamos el ignore a:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="rol", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore 
private List<Usuarios> usuarios= new ArrayList<>();
```